# Options for closing a notification

Tags: node.js, html, notifications, electron

I'm creating an Electron app with the [HTML5 Notification API](https://notifications.spec.whatwg.org/) and would like to have each notification display several options to the user when she closes the notification like so:

[image]

After reading the [MDN documentation for a Notification constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/Notification), I couldn't figure out a way to configure the notification in such a way that it comes with several options ("Install" and "Later" options in the above example) for closing it.

The `actions` attribute within the `options` object (the second argument passed to the `Notification` constructor) seemed promising but the lack of documentation on the "NotificationAction" object makes it hard to understand how to go about implementing this feature.

From the MDN documentation:

> actions: An array of NotificationActions representing the actions
>   available to the user when the notification is presented. These are
>   options the user can choose among in order to act on the action within
>   the context of the notification itself. The action's name is sent to
>   the service worker notification handler to let it know the action was
>   selected by the user.

Currently I only have one option ("Close") when closing a notification.

[image]

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Notification actions are not widely supported at the time of this writing.
[image: Browser Compatability]

For the browsers that do support it, you can use it like this:

```
self.registration.showNotification('New message from Alice', {
    actions: [
        {action: 'like', title: 'Like'},
        {action: 'reply', title: 'Reply'}
    ]
});
```

Then to get what the user had clicked on, something like this:

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    var messageId = event.notification.data;

    event.notification.close();

    if (event.action === 'like') {
        silentlyLikeItem();
    }
    else if (event.action === 'reply') {
        clients.openWindow("/messages?reply=" + messageId);
    }
    else {
        clients.openWindow("/messages?reply=" + messageId);
    }
}, false);
```

You can read on on the specifics at https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/01/notification-actions

To see this in action, you can check out https://tests.peter.sh/notification-generator/#actions=3